# No instance for (Show (FilePath -> IO [FilePath])) arising from a use of ‘print’

Tags: haskell, ghci

I am trying to fix and run every example on the Real World Haskell book and learn something in the process and I got stuck at [chapter 9](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/io-case-study-a-library-for-searching-the-filesystem.html). By reading the comments I got the following code to compile:

`FoldDir.hs`:

```
import ControlledVisit
import Data.Char (toLower)
import Data.Time.Clock (UTCTime(..))
import System.Directory (Permissions(..))
import System.FilePath ((</>), takeExtension, takeFileName)

data Iterate seed
  = Done { unwrap :: seed }
  | Skip { unwrap :: seed }
  | Continue { unwrap :: seed }
    deriving (Show)

type Iterator seed = seed -> Info -> Iterate seed

foldTree :: Iterator a -> a -> FilePath -> IO a
foldTree iter initSeed path = do
  endSeed <- fold initSeed path
  return (unwrap endSeed)
  where
    fold seed subpath = getUsefulContents subpath >>= walk seed
    walk seed (name : names) = do
      let path' = path </> name
      info <- getInfo path'
      case iter seed info of
        done @ (Done _) -> return done
        Skip seed'      -> walk seed' names
        Continue seed'
          | isDirectory info -> do
            next <- fold seed' path'
            case next of
              done @ (Done _) -> return done
              seed''           -> walk (unwrap seed'') names
          | otherwise         -> walk seed' names
    walk seed _ = return (Continue seed)

atMostThreePictures :: Iterator [FilePath]
atMostThreePictures paths info
  | length paths == 3
    = Done paths
  | isDirectory info && takeFileName path == ".svn"
    = Skip paths
  | extension `elem` [".jpg", ".png"]
    = Continue (path : paths)
  | otherwise
    = Continue paths
  where
    extension = map toLower (takeExtension path)
    path = infoPath info

countDirectories count info =
  Continue (if isDirectory info then count + 1 else count)
```

`ControlledVisit.hs`:

```
module ControlledVisit where

import Control.Monad (forM, liftM)
import Data.Time.Clock (UTCTime(..))
import System.FilePath ((</>))
import System.Directory
  ( Permissions(..)
  , getModificationTime
  , getPermissions
  , getDirectoryContents
  )
import Control.Exception
  ( bracket
  , handle
  , SomeException(..)
  )
import System.IO
  ( IOMode(..)
  , hClose
  , hFileSize
  , openFile
  )

data Info = Info
  { infoPath :: FilePath
  , infoPerms :: Maybe Permissions
  , infoSize :: Maybe Integer
  , infoModTime :: Maybe UTCTime
  } deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

getInfo :: FilePath -> IO Info
getInfo path = do
  perms <- maybeIO (getPermissions path)
  size <- maybeIO (bracket (openFile path ReadMode) hClose hFileSize)
  modified <- maybeIO (getModificationTime path)
  return (Info path perms size modified)

traverseDirs :: ([Info] -> [Info]) -> FilePath -> IO [Info]
traverseDirs order path = do
  names <- getUsefulContents path
  contents <- mapM getInfo (path : map (path </>) names)
  liftM concat $ forM (order contents) $ \ info -> do
    if isDirectory info && infoPath info /= path
      then traverseDirs order (infoPath info)
      else return [info]

getUsefulContents :: FilePath -> IO [String]
getUsefulContents path = do
  names <- getDirectoryContents path
  return (filter (`notElem` [".", ".."]) names)

isDirectory :: Info -> Bool
isDirectory = maybe False searchable . infoPerms

maybeIO :: IO a -> IO (Maybe a)
maybeIO act = handle (\ (SomeException _) -> return Nothing) (Just `liftM` act)

traverseVerbose order path = do
  names <- getDirectoryContents path
  let usefulNames = filter (`notElem` [".", ".."]) names
  contents <- mapM getEntryName ("" : usefulNames)
  recursiveContents <- mapM recurse (order contents)
  return (concat recursiveContents)
  where
    getEntryName name = getInfo (path </> name)
    isDirectory info = case infoPerms info of
      Nothing -> False
      Just perms -> searchable perms
    recurse info = do
      if isDirectory info && infoPath info /= path
        then traverseVerbose order (infoPath info)
        else return [info]
```

But when I try to run it in GHCi [as explained in the book](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/io-case-study-a-library-for-searching-the-filesystem.html#x_fQ) it fails with a weird error that as far as I understand is about GHCi itself:

```
Prelude> :l FoldDir.hs
[1 of 2] Compiling ControlledVisit  ( ControlledVisit.hs, interpreted )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( FoldDir.hs, interpreted )
Ok, two modules loaded.
*Main> foldTree atMostThreePictures []

<interactive>:2:1: error:
    • No instance for (Show (FilePath -> IO [FilePath]))
        arising from a use of ‘print’
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

I think I understand the `No instance for (Show (FilePath -> IO [FilePath]))` part but I am clueless about the `print it`. I know `it` is a special variable in GHCi that stores the evaluation result of the last expression and I guess the code is trying to print a function or a monad, but I don't get where it is happening.

Comment: The `foldTree` function expects 3 parameters, but you're passing only 2 (as suggested in the error message).

Comment: Add a `path` argument to your call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as possible - signature of Your function `foldTree` is:

```
foldTree :: Iterator a -> a -> FilePath -> IO a
```

You are supplying it with two arguments, one of type `Iterator [FilePath]` and second of type `FilePath`. Due to default partial application such call returns function with signature:

```
FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
```

GHCI wants to display the result of Your call but it cannot, as this type has no defined instance of typeclass `Show`. And so, it gives You an error telling exactly this.